# How do you deal with a UTF8 buffer?

Tags: ios, swift, buffer

In my project, I'm dealing with a UInt8 buffer. Here's my code:

```swift
let bufferSize = 4096
var buffer = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)
```

Now I need to create another buffer in UTF8 format to command and receive response for a new device, but I'm not sure how to deal with this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UTF8' (aka 'Unicode.UTF8')

```swift
let bufferSize = 4096
var buffer = [UTF8](repeating: 0, count: bufferSize)
```

Comment: `UTF8` aka `Unicode.UTF8` is a `UnicodeCodec`, I doubt that you want to create an array of that type. What you perhaps mean is `UTF8.CodeUnit` – but that is a type alias for `UInt8`, so that would be the same as in your first code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF8 is an encoding, this means a way to convert bytes into actual characters (mainly with `String` class).

So when you are receiving "UTF8", it means you are actually receiving or sending bytes, which, when decoded through UTF8, are characters, or strings.

To manage bytes, you can either use `[UInt8]` arrays, as mentioned, or `Data` class, which is dedicated for this.

Then, you can use this to convert from `[UInt8]` to `String`  :

```swift
let array : [UInt8] = [0x05, 0x26, 0xFD, 0xB5] // example
let data = Data(array)
let resultString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

And to convert from `String` to `[UInt8]`:

```swift
let string = "To be converted to UTF8 bytes..."
let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!
let array = [UInt8](data)
```

So your first code extract is correct.
But your second is not correct. `UTF8` is just an enum (?) representing the UTF8 encoding itself, not a *character* nor a *byte* in UTF8 encoding, so there is no interest in doing an `[UTF8]` array.

Your output can simply be a `String`. I do not think you have an expected argument to be of swift type `UTF8`.

Comment: Big thanks for detailed explanation! My output is a String indeed, seems like I need to modify the part of convert from [UInt8] to String.

My background is not computer science, it may took me a while.

Comment: Not sure why didn't get response back, my reference is [rvndios's code (GitHub)](https://github.com/rvndios/EADemo/blob/master/EADemo.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj)

![Screen Shot](https://imgur.com/a/BZkXTjV).